# Ebean: Unexpected behaviour with associations when inheritance

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-2.5

I have 2 models using "Single Table Inheritance" strategy:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="user_type")
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends Model {
   ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("manager")
public class Manager extends User {
  ....
}
```

I also have `Event` model that has many-to-one association to `Manager`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="events")
public class Event extends Model {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    public Manager user;
}
```

The problem is that each query to `events` automatically does a join with `users` table for fetching discriminator value (value of `user_type` column).

For example:

```
Event.find.where().idEq(100).findUnique();
```

... produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.id c0, t0.name c1, t1.user_type c2, t0.user_id c3 FROM events t0 join users t1 on t1.id = t0.user_id and t1.user_type = 'manager'  where t0.id = 100
```

Why join `users` table?
Why get `user_type` value if it is already present in the query? Ebean is finding `user_type` by `user_type`. Is it a bug?

How to fix this?

It breaks a lot and causes a lot of pain.

**Edit:** The main question is "How to fix this?"

Answer (score 0):

> Why join users table?

As user is part of an inheritance hierarchy it is not know the "type" of user without the discriminator value (`t1.user_type`).

You will notice that Ebean is selecting on the discriminator type column (`t1.user_type`) and the id column of the user (`t0.user_id`). Ebean needs to do this in this case such that it can build a reference bean for the associated user with the correct type.

Comment: As you can see the `user_type` value is already present in the query. It is like "What is the name of the man whoes name is Rob Bygrave?". Don't you think it's silly? Besides, Ebean doesn't need to know the `user_type` of a user if it already knows it's id, since it is `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance, all users have unique ids. Moreover, there are many ways to get `user_type` from the code, not from DB.